# LDAP - windows/xampp (php changing password) - Doesn't show userPassword attribute

Tags: php, windows, apache, xampp, ldap

I've created a php script (with XAMPP server and php_ldap.dll library) to change the AD user password (I'm using the Admin account for auth):

```
    $server         = "ldaps://xx.xx.xx.xx";
    $dn             = "dc=domainname,dc=com";
    $port           = 636;
    ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
    $con = ldap_connect($server, $port);  

    ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    ldap_set_option($con, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);

    $bind = ldap_bind($con, 'CN=Admin,CN=Users,DC=DOMIAN,DC=COM', 'password');

    $user_search = ldap_search($con,$dn,'(sAMAccountName='.$user.')');
    $user_get = ldap_get_entries($con, $user_search);

    $user_entry = ldap_first_entry($con, $user_search);
    $user_dn = ldap_get_dn($con, $user_entry);

    $user           = 'validuser';
    $oldPassword    = 'oldpass';
    $newPassword    = 'newpass';

    $encoded_newPassword = "{SHA}" . base64_encode( pack( "H*", sha1( $newPassword ) ) );

    /* Change the password */
    $entry = array();
    $entry["userPassword"] = "$encoded_newPassword";

    if (ldap_modify($con,$user_dn,$entry) === false){
        $error = ldap_error($con);
        $errno = ldap_errno($con);
        echo "$errno - $error";
    } else {
        echo "yes";
    }
```

Also, I've created a ldap.conf in C:\OpenLDAP\sysconf with:

```
TLS_REQCERT never
```

But the ldap_modify/ldap_mod_replace function return me **TRUE** ("yes") message. The password changing test is with my own user account, but it stills having the same password.

I suspect is the **userPassword** attribute, because when I get the ldap_get_entries from the user, I can't see this attribute, but if I have "all privileges" with the Administrator account, why cannot see the password attr? Do I need more privilegies? or what kind of configuration I need in LDAP/Apache?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried setting "userpassword" instead? In lowercase?

Comment: What is the LDAP server? LDAP is a protocol, not an implementation of this protocol, as SQL is different than MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc. LDAP is the same : Active Directory, OpenLDAP, ApacheDS, etc. Does the configuration of the LDAP directory allows you to retrieve this attribute?

Comment: @Esteban The question clearly mentiones that the server is an AD (which usually means ActiveDirectory). The admin should be able to read that attribute, though note the conjunctive there ;) So better check that csotelo